# How do I prevent totem and other programs from logging all recently played files?

Tags: totem, zeitgeist

This is a frustrating problem, is there any way to prevent totem from logging all of the files I watch? The same goes with picture viewer.

Under Dash -> Privacy, I've turned off logging and disabled it specifically for those problems yet every new file I watch appears in the totem menu.

It leads me to believe that if totem is recording it, then other programs are recording it as well.

Are there any workarounds?

I've already added "gtk-recent-files-max-age = 0" to my gtkrc-2.0 file and the problem persists.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will hide your recently viewed items from the Totem interface.

```
sed -i 's/<separator name="recent-separator"/<!--<separator name="recent-separator"/g' /usr/share/totem/totem.ui
sed -i 's/"recent-placeholder"\/>/"recent-placeholder"\/>-->/g' /usr/share/totem/totem.ui
```

Comment: This will hide them, but they are still recorded and available for someone with access to the machine to find out, right? That is, this doesn't actually **keep them from being logged**, does it?

Answer (score -1):

This will remove your recently viewed items from Totem interface.

```
rm -v ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel
```

Comment: This doesn't keep them from being logged, it just clears them once they have been logged.